# How to remove the quote and bracket from list value

Tags: python, string, list

I have a function to return a list of values, referenced by result:

```
def populate(*args):
    i=1
    result = []
    for arg in args:
        arg = str(cols[i].get_text())
        i+=1
        result.append(arg)
    return result
```

And I want to assign the values from result to different variables:

```
a, b, c = populate(result)
```

Supposing `result = ['LINZ','WLG Cisco BYOL 2','32']`

However I got the following output for a,b,c:

```
**LINZ** 

**['WLG Cisco BYOL 2']**

**32**
```

How to remove `[' ']` and assign it as a string?

Many thanks for your help!

Comment: Could you point what is the content of your `cols` variable?

Comment: In your code, the input is "result", but there isn't any reference for it. I am pullzed for your code.

Comment: cols[i] is just a list, which stores element of HTML tags.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to convert each item in the list to string, then you could make it more simpler:

```
In [12]: a, b, c= [str(item) for item in result]

In [13]: a, b, c
Out[13]: ('LINZ', 'WLG Cisco BYOL 2', '32')

In [14]: a
Out[14]: 'LINZ'

In [15]: b
Out[15]: 'WLG Cisco BYOL 2'

In [16]: c
Out[16]: '32'
```

The function might look like this (minimally modifying your code:

```
def populate(*args):
    result = []
    for arg in args:
        arg = str(arg)
        result.append(arg)
    return result
```

which is just equivalent to:

```
[str(item) for item in result]
```

Comment: I just found another issue, if the function only returns and assigns value to one argument, it still has the [' ']:
b= populate(result)
print b
['WLG Cisco BYOL 2']

tried to change the code to b=str(populate(result)), and still can't get rid of the [' '].

why is that? Many thanks!